# How to deploy Azure webapp to multiple environments without using config transforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, connection-string, appsettings

I have a multi-tier Azure web app which uses EF DB first model. I want to deploy it in dev, test, staging and production environment. Each environment has different database connection string as well as different `ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri` url. Is there any way I can skip using web config transform and just use app settings to manage deployment to multiple environments.

I am able to use connection string from app settings in Azure portal. But not sure how to configure `PostLogoutRedirectUri` in app settings and use that value in web.config.

Comment: Did you try to deploy with publish profile.

Comment: yes but to create a new publish profile I need new build configuration so that connection string etc is different for each environment. i am just wondering if there is any way to skip creating new build configuration at all

Comment: when you create a new slot, you could clone configuration, so I think you don't need to configure all settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But not sure how to configure `PostLogoutRedirectUri` in app settings and use that value in web.config

The following is true for all settings in a .NET application in an Azure App Service:

> **App settings**
>   This section contains name/value pairs that your app will load on start up.
>
> - For .NET apps, these settings are injected into your .NET configuration AppSettings at runtime, overriding existing settings.

Source: [Configure apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)

Simply put, this means:
- if a setting is only in `web.config`, your app will *use* the value from your config file
- if a setting is also under App Settings, it will *override* the value in the config

So put the base/default value in your config, and override it in App Settings when necessary.

**EDIT:**
You should not look at the config to check if the value has been substituted there. The file is **NOT** transformed or altered, the values are injected at runtime. Otherwise, changing a setting under App Settings would mean an app recycle (since it would change the web.config file).

Comment: I tried the exact same thing. I have a key in web.config `<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:333" />`. I created an app setting in the portal with name `ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri` but it did not work. May be I am missing something

Comment: Are you running `ASP.NET`, or `ASP.NET Core`? 'cause there might be a difference there.

Comment: `ASP.NET` not core

Comment: I deleted the existing web transformation and kept just one default i.e. debug. Added `ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri` in web.config as well as app settings with different values. After deploying, the app service editor showed value in web.config as the final value instead picking from app settings

Comment: Well, this is right at the heart of app services and how you can use App Settings under Application Settings to configure your .NET app, so I _do_ think you might be missing something. Have you tried reading the value and logging it somewhere? Because 'it did not work' is kind of vague.

Comment: @Garima don't look at the config! The file is **NOT** transformed, the values are injected at runtime. Otherwise, changing a setting under App Settings would mean an app recycle (since it would change the web.config file).

Comment: sure I will try logging the value too. I just checked final value in web.config in app service editor from azure portal. Got it.